# What's wrong with below jQuery code?

Tags: jquery

I'm not able to trace the error in following code. I tried with firebug but still couldn't get the bug. Can you help me in identifying it?

```
$("#preview_newsletter").click(function() {
      $( "#newsletter_preview" ).dialog({
      height: 140,
      modal: true
      });
    });
```

Comment: why do you think there is an error in the codes ?? have you checked it.. if yes.. post the error message that your are getting

Comment: Please set up a jsFiddle, there's nowhere near enough info there. Also, check the error console...

Comment: Your code is ok. Do you have a div with id #newsletter_preview? (just debugging, i had to ask)

Comment: Are you sure you are not messing ids of #preview_newsletter and #newsletter_preview

Comment: Post more of your relevant code as the HTML one

Answer (score 2):

What about waiting for DOM ready:

```
$(function () {
    $("#preview_newsletter").click(function () {
        $("#newsletter_preview").dialog({
            height: 140,
            modal: true
        });
    });
});
```

Your selectors mean you have one element with ID preview_newsletter and one element with ID newsletter_preview. So for sure, you need both elements in your DOM.

You could not use the ready handler if setting your code in a script tag just before the body's closing tag: `</body>`

Answer (score 0):

Error is you are not including `UI script`

include`jQuery UI 1.9.2` script

```
$(function(){
  $("#preview_newsletter").click(function() {
    $("#newsletter_preview").dialog({
      height: 140,
      modal: true
    });
   });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yammu/)

Comment: As OP seems to say there is no error in console, i suspect this is the click handler which is not fired

Comment: Why Downvote? Can anyone explain. I have checked after removing UI script error occured

Comment: I didn't downvote and i think your info is still usefull even seems not related to OP's issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure about this. I think you are trying to open a dialog window on click of #preview_newsletter.

You have to define the dialog on document ready. Then open it on the click event. While defining dont open it.

```
    var dialog  = "";
    $(document).ready(function() {

        dialog = $( "#newsletter_preview" ).dialog({
            height: 140,
            modal: true,
            // code for preventing open it
        });
    });

    $("#preview_newsletter").click(function() {
        dialog.open()
    })
```